# Laravel | how to change route if user is not authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I don't know If this is possible with laravel or what is the best way to achieve it, i wan't if user click to like post or add to favorites and he is not authenticated to showing login form,

I want every visitor to have access to all posts, i have used before `if(auth::check())` in my view to hide or display the buttons (like & favorite) if user authenticated, but i don't like this way. i want to display the buttons to all visitors but when a Unauthenticated user click on like button redirecting to login page.
I tried to add this method to my routes but seems not working

```
if (Auth:check()){
  Route::post('/favorite/{post}', 'SiteController@favorite');
  Route::post('/unfavorite/{post}', 'SiteController@unFavorite');

  Route::post('/like/{post}', 'SiteController@like');
  Route::post('/update/{post}', 'SiteController@update');
  Route::post('/unlike/{post}', 'SiteController@unLike');

} else {

  Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to use [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) for things like this. Group the routes you want only logged in users to have access to and use a middleware on that route to check if the user is authenticated.

Example:
`web.php`

```
<?php
// Routes for logged in users.
$router->group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function($router) {
    $router->get('foobar', ['as' => 'foobar', 'uses' => 'FooController@index']);
});

// Routes for all users.
$router->get('bar', ['as' => 'bar', 'uses' => 'BarController@index']);
```

`App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest(route('bar'));
            }
        }

        view()->share('user', Auth::user());

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then in `App\Http\Kernel.php` you add this to your `$routeMiddleware` array:

```
'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

Comment: I want every visitor to have access to all posts, i have used before If (auth::check()) in my view to hide and display the buttons (like & favorite) if user authenticated, but i don't like this way. i want to display the buttons to all visitors but when a Unauthenticated user click on like button redirecting to login page

Answer (score 1):

To make the like button visible you have to remove the `auth::check())` in your views and add this to your `web.php`:

```
// Routes for guest users
// Add here the route for your posts


// Routes for logged-in users
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  Route::post('/favorite/{post}', 'SiteController@favorite');
  Route::post('/unfavorite/{post}', 'SiteController@unFavorite');

  Route::post('/like/{post}', 'SiteController@like');
  Route::post('/update/{post}', 'SiteController@update');
  Route::post('/unlike/{post}', 'SiteController@unLike');
}
```

Comment: I want like button to be visible for any one, but when someone not authenticated click on like button redirect him to login page. that's it

Comment: You mentioned that a couple of times. Did you tried any code in the answers? If yes, what happend? Did you got an error? Is the Like button not visible?

Comment: Yes i mention it cuz every time i got the wrong answer, I have middleware in my route, and the button accessible only by authenticated users, when someone else click nothing happen, and the response in console.log is `MethodeNotAllowed` "unauthenticated" and that's correct, but i want to automatically redirect him to login page after the click

Comment: This means you doing an Ajax request? If so, you have to redirect to Login in the fail part of your ajax call.

Comment: yes, am doing request with axios, thanks i will look for that